# how to get uid in mailkit?

Tags: c#, mailkit

my code is:

```
 using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient())
 {
     // Connect to the server and authentication and then 
     var inbox = client.Inbox;
     inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
     int messageCount = inbox.Count - 1;
     for (int i = messageCount; i > 0 ; i--)
     {
           var visitor = new HtmlPreviewVisitor();
           MimeMessage message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
           message.Accept(visitor);
           // how can get uid for this message
     }
 }
```

I wand to save uid . how can get uid for message ?

```
MimeMessage message =inbox.GetMessage(UniqueId.Parse(uid));
```

Comment: What package is this using? `MimeMessage` doesn't appear to be standard C#, so it would be nice to add the `using` section so we know where the class comes from

Comment: add MimeKit ,MailKit and MailKit.Net.Imap.

Comment: Looking in the class document, there doesn't appear to be anything of that type:
http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimeMessage.htm, the closest I can see is the property `MessageId`. Is that what you are looking for? If not, what do you need the `uid` for?

Comment: I wand save uid in place and use it for get content of message. MimeMessage message =inbox.GetMessage(UniqueId.Parse(uid));

Comment: I make list of message , then user select message from list.I want save uid to get this message from inbox.

Comment: So you are OK with creating your own `UID`? If so, you could create a collection of `UID` and `MimeMessage` or create a class object that holds these properties. Then at point of creation of the message you would call `Guid.NewGuid();` to have a `UID`

Comment: is have way for it(make list message and user select it then we get  message selected for user)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The way to get the UID for a particular message using MailKit is to use the `Fetch()` method on the `ImapFolder` instance and pass it the `MessageSummaryItem.UniqueId` enum value.

Typically you'll want to get the UIDs of the messages in the folder *before* you fetch the actual message(s), like so:

```
// fetch some useful metadata about each message in the folder...
var items = folder.Fetch (0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Size | MessageSummaryItems.Flags);

// iterate over all of the messages and fetch them by UID
foreach (var item in items) {
    var message = folder.GetMessage (item.UniqueId);

    Console.WriteLine ("The message is {0} bytes long", item.Size.Value);
    Console.WriteLine ("The message has the following flags set: {0}", item.Flags.Value);
}
```

The `Flags` includes things like `Seen`, `Deleted`, `Answered`, etc. The `Flagged` flag means that the message has been flagged as "important" by the user.